# For loop takes more time to run when i is a large number

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
    for(number=3;number<=5;number++){
          window.setTimeout(
            (function (number){ 
              return function() {

                alert("hi");

              }
          })(number),number * 3500)
        }


 /*for(number=0;number<=5;number++){
          window.setTimeout(
            (function (number){ 
              return function() {

                alert("hi");

              }
          })(number),number * 3500)
        }*/
```

For some unknown reason when "number" is larger loop takes more time to start iterating. How can I change the code in such  way that alert will be called instantly? 
Note: I need delays in iterations so don't offer to get rid of them
Thanks in advance

Comment: ? Because the timeout is a multiplication of number and 3500, the bigger the number the longer the wait...

Comment: :'D Oh God it is obvious. I feel awkward now)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The second argument to `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is the delay you want the window to wait before executing the supplied code.

So when you do this:

```
setTimeout(someFunction, x * 3500)
```

That delay will depend on the value of `x`.  If `x` is larger, the resulting timeout will be larger.  In order to use a constant time instead of a variable one, use a constant value instead of a variable:

```
setTimeout(someFunction, 3500)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(number=3;number<=5;number++){
      window.setTimeout(
        (function (number){ 
          return function() {

            alert("hi");

          }
      })(number), 3500)
    }
```

try this instead, like timenomad said, the timeout is a multiplication of number and 3500